# Divs com FLEXBOX não alinham corretamente

Tags: css, flexbox

Sou novo com FLEXBOX e estou desenvolvendo um layout que seguiria essa estrutura:

[image: imagem1]
Porém só consegui chegar a esse resultado:

[image: imagem2]

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #CCC;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.div1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #FF0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  order: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .div1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #FF0;
    flex-grow: 0;
    order: 1;
  }
}

.div2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #FC0;
  align-self: flex-end;
  flex-grow: 0;
  order: 2;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .div2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #FC0;
    flex-grow: 0;
    order: 2;
  }
}

.div3 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #F90;
  align-self: flex-end;
  flex-grow: 0;
  order: 3;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .div3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #F90;
    flex-grow: 0;
    order: 3;
  }
}

.div4 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #F60;
  align-self: flex-end;
  flex-grow: 0;
  order: 4;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .div4 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #F60;
    flex-grow: 0;
    order: 4;
  }
}

.div5 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #0C6;
  flex-grow: 0;
  order: 5;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .div5 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #0C6;
    flex-grow: 0;
    order: 5;
  }
}

.div6 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #396;
  align-self: flex-end;
  flex-grow: 0;
  order: 6;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .div6 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #396;
    flex-grow: 0;
    order: 6;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">1</div>
  <div class="div2">2</div>
  <div class="div3">3</div>
  <div class="div4">4</div>
  <div class="div5">5</div>
  <div class="div6">6</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Desculpe, eu quis simplificar a situação e por isso postei só o bloco do layout que teoricamente importaria para a solução do problema. Mas a solução (que funciona perfeitamente no cenário apresentado) apresentada pelo hugocsl não funciona no cenário "completo". Segue a nova imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse tipo de layout fica melhor e mais fácil de fazer usando grid.

Comment: Eu estava fazendo antes com "float" e "clear:both" e me indicaram o "flexbox". Tinha até aberto um tópico antes mas como o assunto foi caminhando para o flexbox tive que abrir esse tópico...

Comment: Deixei uma resposta ai com flex, não sei se da para falar que uma técnica é melhor que a outra, mas que é possível fazer dos dois jeitos vc pode conferir nas respostas :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue uma opção com flex, que tem tem a opção de usar o atributo `order` nos filhos e pode ser distribuído em colunas usando o `flex-direction:column`.

O detalhe é que a `div` 1 ocupa 70% da altura, e a `div` 5 ocupa 30% da altura, assim a primeira coluna fica completamente preenchida por esses dois elementos, e o restante dos elementos filhos vão ser "alinhados" na segunda coluna.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**EDIT**

Como a `div 5` vai ter uma altura fixa, e a `div 1` não, basta fazer um `calc` na altura da `div 1`, ficaria assim por exemplo `height: calc(100% - var(--altura));`, a na `div 5` a altura é `height: var(--altura);`

Veja que `var(--altura)` é a variável CSS que vc vai definir no `:root`, assim vc não precisa ficar mudando o valor em vários lugares, vc muda no `:root` o valo da variável e esse valor muda em todos os lugares, **e assim a altura da div 1 será sempre 100% menos a antura da div 5**

```
:root {
    --altura: 100px; 
}
```

Segue o código referente a imagem acima:

```css
:root {
    --altura: 100px;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}
[class^="div"] {
    width: 50%;
}
.div1 {
    height: calc(100% - var(--altura));
    order: 1;
    background-color:#FF0;
}
.div5 {
    height: var(--altura);
    order: 1;
    background-color:#0C6;
}
.div2 {
   background-color:#FC0;
}
.div3 {
   background-color:#F90;
}
.div4 {
   background-color:#F60;
}
.div6 {
   background-color:#396;
}
.div2, .div3, .div4, .div6 {
    order: 2;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    :root {
        --altura: initial;
    }
    .container {
        height: auto;
    }
    [class^="div"] {
        width: 100%;
        order: initial;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1">1</div>
    <div class="div2">2</div>
    <div class="div3">3</div>
    <div class="div4">4</div>
    <div class="div5">5</div>
    <div class="div6">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hugocsl existe uma forma de fazer isso sem que as alturas (70% e 30%) sejam setadas? porque as divs tem altura variável em px...

Comment: Para esclarecer, todas as divs terão altura fixa em px menos a div1.... essa será variável.

Comment: @JohnSnowDad tem como sim, já que vc sabe a altura da div5 basta que a altura da div1 seja 100% - Altura Div5. Leia o **EDIT** que fiz na resposta acima que ensino a fazer isso de forma pratica. O código já foi atualizado tb para ser usado com a Variável

Comment: hugocsl... cara funcionou sim! Eu agradeço demais a ajuda e o seu tempo. Deixa eu tirar uma última dúvida com vc: existe a possibilidade de obter o mesmo resultado sem ter que setar a altura do container como 100%?

Comment: Eu digo isso porque esse bloco todo ficará dentro de um bloco maior (containergeral, header, content, footer)... quando a altura do .container fica 100% distorce o layout todo.

Comment: Para esse código funcionar alguém tem que ter uma altura definida. Ou a div 1 ou o container... Mas o que ei não entendi é pq a div 5 tem que vir depois da div 1, ali deveria ser a div 2 ou a div 6, o modelo que vc está tentando construir não é o adequado no HTML, to falando do HTML não do CSS. No HTML vc tem que bolar uma forma que fique mais coerente. Ficar fazendo "jeitinho" no CSS não é o ideal... Pensa direito nesse layout, e como vc vai distribuir as coisas, mas a div 5 "casando" com a div 1 atrapalha muito as coisa e não faz sentido algum...

Comment: A div5 é uma espécie de rodapé da div1 (conteúdo)... as divs 2,3 e 4 são conteúdos complementares da div1.... por isso a div5 fica sempre abaixo da div1 (desktop/tablet) ou da div1 + complementares (mobile). A div6 é um conteúdo não relacionado a div1.

Comment: De qualquer forma gostaria de agradecer a ajuda. Vou avaliar esse cenário e ver se consigo remodelá-lo pois está dificultando as coisas ao invés de ajudar. Grande abraço a todos e que Deus os abençoe!